# File name and its path as dictionary not showing all results

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I've got the text file with paths, like:

`/path/to/file.ext`

I need to split those paths into dictionary so the `key` would be path excluding file and `value` – file name with its extension. I've managed this with below code:

```
base = {}
with open ('text.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        key,val = line.strip('\n').rsplit('/',1)
        base[key] = val
```

I've used `.strip('\n')` to get rid of newlines and `.rsplit('/',1)` to split my whole path based on last `/` in path.

The code is basically working, but… It doesn't process whole `txt` file.

Processing file with 9900+ paths, I got base with less than 3000 elements (keys+values). I checked that using `len(base)`.

1. All paths were made with bash `find` command so are ok.
2. Path names does not include any quirky characters.
3. Deleting `.strip('\n')` doesn't change anything.
4. I am using **Python 2.7.10**.

Comment: If two paths have the same directory, the second one will overwrite the first one. Furthermore it is advicable not do path processing yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Use `os.path` module to process the directories.
Assuming a file with a single line `/path/to/file.ext`, the following code

```
import os

with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        print(os.path.dirname(line))
        print(os.path.basename(line))
```

Outputs

```
/path/to
file.ext
```

Now, as @ Willem Van Onsem explained in the comment, using `os.path.dirname` as the key will overwrite previous paths to files in the same directory. To remedy this you will need to use lists as the values:

```
import os
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        d[os.path.dirname(line)].append(os.path.basename(line))
```

Now consider:

```
/path/to/file1.ext
/path/to/file2.ext
/path/to/file3.ext
/another/path/to/file4.ext
```

After running the above code, `print(d)` will output

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'/path/to': ['file1.ext', 'file2.ext', 'file3.ext'],
                             '/another/path/to': ['file4.ext']})
```

Comment: Thank you, now I got it to get all lines/paths into dictionary! Now I need to think, how to process them – how to search for individual file and get its path.